# np reshape within pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

Arise Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional.

I'll present the problem with a toy example to be clear.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Initial dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[10,15,12,14],[20,30,10,43]], "R":[2,2] ,"C":[2,2]})
>>df

       A                    C   R
0   [10, 15, 12, 14]    2   2
1   [20, 30, 10, 43]    2   2
```

Conversion to numpy array and reshape:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
df.apply(lambda x: print(x[0],(x[1],x[2])) ,axis=1)
df['A_reshaped'] = df.apply(lambda x[['A','R','C']]: np.reshape(x[0],(x[1],x[2])),axis=1)
df

       A                    C    R           A_reshaped
0   [10, 15, 12, 14]    2   2        [[10,15],[12,14]]
1   [20, 30, 10, 43]    2   2        [[20,30],[10,43]]
```

Someone know the reason? It seems to not accept 2 dimensional arrays in pandas cells but it's strange...

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Your last lambda is strange: it's `lambda x`: something that doesn't have to do with `x`. Can you go back a step and describe what you want to do?

Comment: For sure. reshape the monodimensioal array in A with parameters given by R and C. Write this new matrix into A.
Now I edit the example according to the expected result.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, now. The `apply` doesn't seem to work directly, but `zip` seems able to bypass it. Since this creates several new objects, I don't think vectorization is much of an issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` directly doesn't work - the return value is a `numpy` 2d array, and placing it back in the DataFrame confuses Pandas, for some reason.

This seems to work, though:

```
df['reshaped'] = pd.Series([a.reshape((c, r)) for (a, c, r) in zip(df.A, df.C, df.R)])

>>> df
                  A  C  R              reshaped
0  [10, 15, 12, 14]  2  2  [[10, 15], [12, 14]]
1  [20, 30, 10, 43]  2  2  [[20, 30], [10, 43]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!